# Why is this question on hold and marked as primarily opinion based?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, close-reasons

[This question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/28163/do-the-recorded-sounds-from-the-sun-sound-like-aum-in-the-vedas) related to sound from the Sun is on hold for primarily opinion based. I have provided multiple articles which are discussing the subject.

Could you please explain what it makes an opinion based question even with the multiple article info provided with the question?

I have done an edit to question after it was on hold. @Mods: Could you please check those edits and suggest me what kind of edit can I do to make it on-topic if it still does not fit the policies?

Comment: Besides the fact that I can't really find an example of the claim, what distinguishes a sound like "aum" from a sound not like "aum", besides personal opinion on what "aum" should sound like?

Comment: @Sklivvz: It is not personal opinion and there are multiple links provided  discussing the topic. If people are not going to look the references provided, then nothing can be done on this. A simple youtube search on 'sound of sun Aum' will give multiple results but as it is not accepted in SE, provided article links. Does that meet the requirements?

Answer (score 4):

The opinion comes in when you ask "*Does this sound like AUM?*" Some people may hear a similarity, and others won't. Like I commented on the question, all three samples in the video sound very different to me, so I'm *of the opinion* that the answer is no. However, I realize that others may think it does.

The question "*Is this the sound of the sun?*" could be a somewhat better question, but it really boils down to how you define "sound". The linked article says that scientists have altered the signal considerably to produce the sound in the video, so it's hard to call that one. Either way, *that* question isn't clearly asked, and it's mixed up with the opinion-based AUM claim.

Comment: "Does this sound like AUM?" is just a part of the question and for sure one can answer 'yes' or 'no'. But I don't think an answer with just 'YES/NO' will be acceptable for the SE community. There are related questions in the  description and I expect a detailed answer, not just a Yes/No.

Comment: Also as you mentioned in this answer, "Is this the sound of the sun?"  is already asked in the question in another form "how authentic is this video from Telegraph news paper?"

Comment: "Does this sound like AUM?" is as answerable as "Does this cloud look like a face?". IMO it should be removed completely, because there's no *objective* answer. For the other question, I said it's *there*, but not clearly asked, because it's buried in the other. The AUM portion is even the title question, and distracts from the possibly interesting "Is this even 'sound'?" angle.

Comment: IMO Telegraph won't give a fake news and video without any base. There are links provided for supporting the AUM part in the question and removing it just make the question like 'Is this video fake?' and it is unfair to put on hold for this reason.

Comment: @MoonMind: I do not understand your comment. You haven't addressed Geobits objections. Which of the two questions are you skeptical of?

Comment: @Oddthinking: There are two questions asked towards the end of the question description and those are 'how authentic is this video from Telegraph news paper?' and 'Are there any statements from NASA or any justifiable sources regarding this?'. As Geobits mentioned, title of the question is an objective one for sure, but for answering that people need to answer both these questions. Just asking 'Does this sound is from Sun or how it is generated?', these queries will not be suitable skeptics.SE. My emphasize is on whether there are statements from Nasa or any other scientific authorities.

Comment: @MoonMind: I continue to be confused. "title of the question is an objective one for sure" No, I think that is wrong. Is your key question any of these? 1) "Did these recordings come from NASA?" 2) "Were these sounds generated (only) from data collected from the Sun ?" 3) "Did NASA scientists claim that the Sun sounds like AUM?"

Comment: Yes, the first and third questions are. They are asked in a slightly different way, but that could have caused all these confusions. 1) "Did these recordings come from NASA?" this is asked as 'how authentic is this video from Telegraph news paper?' 3)"Did NASA scientists claim that the Sun sounds like AUM?" is asked as 're there any statements from NASA or any justifiable sources regarding this?'.

Comment: @MoonMind: Great. I went to edit the question to make that clear, but I encountered two problems. You first question isn't notable, because two of the three sources attribute the music to astronomers in the UK, not NASA. The second question isn't notable because none of the sources claim that NASA claim it sounds like AUM. In fact the first link explicitly denies NASA said that.